# How to implement correctly onLayout() method in CustomView?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a Custom View, that is extend `ViewGroup`. It is quite logical that I must implement onLayout method. I've try to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219784/how-to-correctly-override-onlayout-method-in-a-viewgroup-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515798/android-viewgroup-what-should-i-do-in-the-onlayout-override) answers, but actually can not understand what I need to do exactly.

**Some provisional information :**

I have a `ViewGroup` and all data passed to this `ViewGroup` **pass via** `Adapter`. It very similar to `ListView & Adapter` communication mechanism.

[image]

My case is the same

[image]

When I looked answers for the questions above, I've mentioned that ViewGroup before layouting knows, what the count of children he has.

```
final int childCount = getChildCount();
```

In my case I doesn't have any idea how to told `ViewGroup`

```
"Hey you have <value> children!".
```

So I need probably more explanation of `onLayout` implementation manual.

Comment: `I have a ViewGroup and all data passed to this ViewGroup pass via Adapter` so you probably need to extend `android.widget.AdapterView<T extends android.widget.Adapter>`

Comment: @pskink looks like an idea. I will try.